# How the headers of the standard library are installed in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, glibc, libc

I have an annoying problem with a library siginfo.h. I need a version of this library that contains the structure of siginfo_t with a field for handling SIGSYS signals.

For isntance, the version of structure as I need can be found here : 
http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/bits/siginfo.h.html

The version that is automatically included using the #include  is the version in 
/usr/include/bits/siginfo.h that misses this field. However, there is another version of the same library in asm-generic that provides the fields I need. The kernel contains two files called  siginfo.h but they don not contain the structure siginfo_t. I thought that this problem could be solved by updating glibc but in the latest version of glibc (2.17) there is a completely different version again, and not what I need.

Now I am bit confused, how headers of the standard libraries are actually installed? 
Should I activate compiling options to have this structure?

Answer (score 0):

What is available in the member `union {} _sifields` of the `siginfo_t` depends on which kernel you are using.

Kernel 3.6.4 definitly defines:

```
 /* SIGSYS */
 struct {
   void __user *_call_addr; /* calling user insn */
   int _syscall;   /* triggering system call number */
   unsigned int _arch;     /* AUDIT_ARCH_* of syscall */
 } _sigsys;
```

Kernel 2.6.32 does not.

I do not know when it was introduced exactly.

Answer (score -1):

The header file is searched as the following order in gcc:
1) The path identified by the -I option;
2) The path in the env vars, C_INCLUDE_PATH, CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH, OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH;
3) The system path, like "/usr/include", etc. 
So you can use the "-I" option to chang the header file searching path. 
And, you may need to use "-L" option to chang the library path.

Comment: I know how the linker works. The problem i how these libraries are installed in the operating system.